# How to know the week numbre from a goiven date in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, date, dayofweek, week-number

For Example, when I give it 01/01/2020 it should know that it's week 1 or 12/03/2020 it is week 13. All this in a Laravel app.

Comment: By the Gregorian calendar, 12/03/2020 is actually week 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it implements DateTimeInterface You can use DateTime::format() method with 'W'. More info and usecases [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

[image]